# node keep telling me node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 throw err;

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

For a few days I have not been able to create any project using node on my PC, since when installing dependencies it gives me the same error.
For example, I want to use vite and I install it without problem, but when I do npm run dev it says

```
"[path of my proyect]\node_modules\.bin\" not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Usuario\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I noticed that it was not that specific installation of vite since in a different directory, I created an electron project and at the time of running the "electron ." command it gave me a similar error:

```
"[in this case it seems not to be the full path of my project since it seems to be cut since the name of the folder that contains it has a space]" not recognized as an internal or external command,
program or executable batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Usuario\electron\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I tried

- uninstall and reinstall node
- in the project directory, delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file and then run the "npm i" command again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case the parent directory was named with &, just re-name it